# Dynamic number of ImageViews based on user input in xml

Tags: java, android, xml, list, imageview

I'm working on an Android app in which the user must be able to upload an image from their camera roll to be displayed in various activities.
I have never used XML before, so I'm not sure if this is possible, but I would like to be able to create a list of ImageViews whose size can change as the user uploads or deletes photos. I know how to create a linked list data structure, but I don't know how to edit the XML file dynamically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit the XML code dynamically. However, you can set up some properties in the XML code which will allow your `ImageView` to change their size dynamically.

Firstly, you should set the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to `wrap_content`. Secondly, set the image(s) to your ImageView(s) by the `src` property of XML or by the `setImageResource()` method of `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

What's stopping you from adding the selected images in a RecyclerView like

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecycler);
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(photosList);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can use Intent chooser to choose images using

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
```

And handling the result on `onActivityResult()`. Please note that `Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` works only on API 18+.

[This](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) tutorial might be helpful to learn more about RecyclerView